# browser.storage.local.set doesn't seem to have any effect

Tags: javascript, local-storage, firefox-addon-webextensions

I'm developing a Firefox extension. It's loaded temporarily (via about:debugging) and I'm trying to use the local storage API. The following screenshots are of the extension's debug console.

First I set a value:

[image]

But it doesn't seem to be there:

[image]

I do have the "storage" permission in my manifest and my extension has an ID.

Comment: I've looked into it a bit and I don't think the `localStorage` in the browser is the same as the `storage.local` for an extension. Does it work if you try to get the value again once it's set?

Comment: @kingdaro Damnit, yes, that seems to work. I thought I'd already tried that.

Comment: @kingdaro Please add your comment as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `localStorage` in the browser is not the same as the `storage.local` for an extension. Instead, try getting the value once it's set and log it from there.

Comment: You should be able to inspect the browser.storage by opening a dev tools window for the extension (i.e. not for a browser tab). See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Add-ons/WebExtensions/Debugging#Developer_tools_toolbox